# My discord bot commands are not working whenever I try them (with and without syntax both) bot not speaking

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

this is my code the ide gives no error but still my bot does not speaks up if you can help then please ;-;

```
import discord
import requests
import random
import os
import flask
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '.')
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Bot ready to launch as {0.user}'.format(client))
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(':ping_pong: PONG!')
@client.command(name='test', aliases=['testcommand','testing'])
async def test(ctx, arg):
    return ctx.send(arg)
    
@client.command(name='purge')
async def clear(ctx, amount:int):
      await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run the bot before you've defined commands for it. Try moving this line:

```
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

To the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line 11 and add

```py
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

to the end.